# error with an aggregate function but parses fine

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble with this query

```
CREATE VIEW qryMonthlyFeesToCollectSummary1
AS
  SELECT ContractID,
         Round(Sum([CreditAmount] * ( ( 1
                                        + COALESCE((SELECT Max(MonthlyRate) 
                                                    FROM tblCases 
                                                    WHERE LEFT(CaseID, 4) = [ContractID] AND CaseStatus = 'Open Case'), 
                                                    0.0199) ) / 30 ) * Exp(30 - 1)), 2) AS InterestCredit
  FROM   tblCredits
  GROUP  BY tblCredits.ContractID,
            (SELECT Count(*)
             FROM   tblInterestPayments
             WHERE  ContractMainID = [ContractID]
                    AND ( PaymentDate IS NULL
                           OR ( PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
                                AND Bounced <> 0
                                AND RetrySuccessful IS NULL ) ))
  HAVING (SELECT Count(*)
          FROM   tblInterestPayments
          WHERE  ContractMainID = [ContractID]
                 AND ( PaymentDate IS NULL
                        OR ( PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
                             AND Bounced <> 0
                             AND RetrySuccessful IS NULL ) )) = 0;
```

it errors out as shown below even though it parses fine. Please help! Thanks so much!

> Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Procedure qryMonthlyFeesToCollectSummary1,
>   Line 11 Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used
>   for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Procedure qryMonthlyFeesToCollectSummary1,
>   Line 5 Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression
>   containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Almost certainly you need some joins in there instead of subqueries.

Comment: I tried to use a LEFT OUT join but it's still bugging out. This was the original code. Same for the 2nd select statement in the HAVING section. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE VIEW qryMonthlyFeesToCollectSummary1
AS
  SELECT ContractID,
         Round(Sum([CreditAmount] * ( ( 1
                                        + COALESCE((SELECT Max(MonthlyRate) 
                                                    FROM tblCases 
                                                    WHERE LEFT(CaseID, 4) = [ContractID] AND CaseStatus = 'Open Case'), 
                                                    0.0199) ) / 30 ) * Exp(30 - 1)), 2) AS InterestCredit
  FROM   tblCredits
  WHERE (SELECT Count(*)
          FROM   tblInterestPayments
          WHERE  ContractMainID = tblCredits.[ContractID]
                 AND ( PaymentDate IS NULL
                        OR ( PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
                             AND Bounced <> 0
                             AND RetrySuccessful IS NULL ) )) = 0
  GROUP  BY tblCredits.ContractID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got it right. Try to properly alias the table names and each column used in the query.

```
CREATE VIEW qryMonthlyFeesToCollectSummary1
AS
  SELECT   tblCredits.ContractID
         , Round(Sum([CreditAmount] * ( ( 1
              + COALESCE(Max(MonthlyRate) , 0.0199) ) / 30 ) 
                * Exp(30 - 1)), 2) AS InterestCredit
  FROM   tblCredits
  INNER JOIN tblCases            ON LEFT(CaseID, 4) = [ContractID] 
                                AND CaseStatus = 'Open Case'
  INNER JOIN tblInterestPayments ON  ContractMainID = [ContractID]
  WHERE PaymentDate IS NULL
       OR ( PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
            AND Bounced <> 0
            AND RetrySuccessful IS NULL ) 
  GROUP  BY tblCredits.ContractID
  HAVING Count(*) = 0;
```

Comment: Almost there. Still getting the error on the aggregate MAX.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
SELECT 
    Credits.ContractID,
    ROUND(SUM(Credits.CreditAmount * ( ( 1 + COALESCE(Cases.MaxMonthlyRate,0.0199) ) / 30 ) * Exp(30 - 1)), 2) AS InterestCredit
FROM   
    tblCredits Credits
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT 
            Max(Cases.MonthlyRate) MaxMonthlyRate
        FROM 
            tblCases Cases 
        WHERE 
            LEFT(Cases.CaseID, 4) = Credits.ContractID
            AND Cases.CaseStatus = 'Open Case'
    )Cases
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL
        FROM tblInterestPayments Payments
        WHERE  
            Payments.ContractMainID = Credits.ContractID
            AND ( 
                Payments.PaymentDate IS NULL
                OR ( 
                    Payments.PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
                    AND Payments.Bounced <> 0
                    AND Payments.RetrySuccessful IS NULL 
                ) 
            )
    )
GROUP BY
    Credits.ContractID
```

The errors you are experienced are encountered when you try to use an aggregate function (MAX, MIN, AVG, etc.) inside a subquery that is inside an expression that is already using an aggregate function. The remove them, I moved that subquery out of the select clause and into an outer apply. I used a Outer apply because you tagged the questions as SQL server and the subquery is performing an aggregate. In other databases you would use a left join.

Also, I moved the tblInterestPayments subquery into a NOT EXISTS clause. Since you are checking for the non existence of rows in the table matching a criteria, this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
CREATE VIEW qryMonthlyFeesToCollectSummary1
AS
  SELECT 
    ContractID,
    ROUND(SUM([CreditAmount] * ( ( 1  + COALESCE(max_monthlyRate, 0.0199) ) / 30 ) * 
EXP(30 - 1)), 2) AS InterestCredit
      FROM   
        tblCredits c LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT 
            ContractMainID 
        FROM 
            tblInterestPayments  
        WHERE 
            PaymentDate IS NULL  OR 
            (  Bounced <> 0   AND RetrySuccessful IS NULL )) i ON
        c.ContractID = i.ContractMainID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT 
            LEFT(CaseID, 4) AS left_caseID4,
            MAX(MonthlyRate) AS max_monthlyRate
         FROM 
            tblCases 
         WHERE 
            CaseStatus = 'Open Case'
        GROUP BY
            LEFT(caseid,4)) s ON
        c.contractID = s.left_caseID4
      WHERE
        i.ContractMainID IS NULL
      GROUP  BY 
        ContractID
```